# How can I make an npm Jest script cross-platform without it looking insane?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, npm, jestjs

The project I'm working on has an npm script which runs Jest unit tests. It was written on a Mac, and I'm trying to make it cross-platform. The script looks like this:

```
"node --harmony node_modules/.bin/jest src/spec/ut"
```

The first thing I fixed is that the Jest binary doesn't run on Windows, so I changed it to this:

```
"node --harmony node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js src/spec/ut"
```

Now at least Jest runs, but it doesn't like the `src/spec/ut` part, which is the `testPathPattern` - i.e. telling it only to run tests which are within `src/spec/ut`

Most node commands on Windows seem happy with *nix-style directory separators, but this one doesn't, because the `testPathPattern` is treated as a regex, and `/` is not the same thing as `\`.

After some experimentation, I discovered that the Windows equivalent of the above is as follows:

```
"node --harmony node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js src\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\spec\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ut"
```

(To save you counting, that's **sixteen** backslashes. I know.)

SO I ought to be able to make it cross-platform by doing something like:

```
"node --harmony node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js src(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\|/)spec(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\|/)ut"
```

(Although I just tried and... that doesn't parse as json)

But I'm trying to write JavaScript here, not Perl. And I can't help thinking that there *must* be a saner way of doing this.

Can anyone suggest a saner way of doing this?

Comment: I'm curious to the answer to this too.

Comment: If anyone's wondering the correct but still insane way of doing it, it's:
`"node --harmony node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js \"src(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\|/)spec(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\|/)ut\""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jest allows you to [specify configuration in package.json or as a separate config file](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html). This config can include either a [testMatch property](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testmatch-array-string)  (glob pattern to match test files) or a [testRegex property](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testregex-string) (regex pattern to match test files), depending on your needs.

Moving the test pattern out of the CLI call should avoid any cross-platform funniness. Then you can just amend the npm script to point to the config:

```
"node --harmony node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --config=your-config.json"
```

Comment: That seems to have solved one error, but given me a whole bunch of new ones.

...the setting didn't work as expected:
`{
    "testMatch": ["src/spec/ut/**/*.spec.js"]
}`

But if I change it to
`{
    "testMatch": ["**/src/spec/ut/**/*.spec.js"]
}`
then it at least finds the unit tests.

Unfortunately, most of them fail, because it doesn't seem to recognise ES6 any more. It doesn't like `import` and `export` statements, so I get a whole bunch of errors along the lines of:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: Oops, my bad, just forgot to move the `transform` parameter out of `package.json`